# InitializeComponent() keeps being generated rather than using the one in my designer

Tags: c#

I have a InitializeComponent() inside of my `.designer` like so:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(accountcreator));
        this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
        this.fileToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.closeToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.statusStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
        this.status = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this.total = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
        this.start = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.radioButton1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.statusStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.total)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
```

I've removed the rest because it's a long file, anyway, when  I click my form like so:
[image]

It is blank, and I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'accountcreator.InitializeComponent()' and
>   'accountcreator.InitializeComponent()'

Whenever I double click my form, at the very bottom, there's another function:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // accountcreator
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Name = "accountcreator";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.accountcreator_Load_5);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

But whenever I delete it, it keeps generating the same function and not allowing me to procceed, how can I using the initialize function inside my file.designer.cs rather than the one that keeps generating in my file.cs?

Comment: It’s a better pattern to use a separate `.Designer.cs` file for your form, such as is generated when using the `Form` template when creating a new file in your project. The way that Designer generates code might be getting confused, but it is less likely to become confused if you let it have full control over its own, `.Designer.cs` file.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, updated my op with the .designer.cs

Comment: So instead of generating it to the `Form1.Designer.cs` it’s writing it to the `Form1.cs`? Have you tried taking the version it wrote in your `Form1.cs` and copying it to the `Form1.Designer.cs`? Did you change the class name or namespace name of either your `Form1.cs` or `Form1.Designer.cs`?

Comment: It is the kind of mishap that occurs when the project file got damaged and the Designer.cs file is no longer associated with the form's .cs file.  Ought to be visible in Solution Explorer with the Designer.cs file no longer hidden in a sub-node of the form's node.  Fixable by restoring from source control or editing the .csproj file by hand and restoring the DependentUpon element.